# Intuitive idea behind the torque about a point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

The text defines the torque of a particle system as being connected with the axis of rotation. "Taken two particles of masses m connected to a thin rod of negligible mass etc", but later when the text explains the torque due to gravity defines the torque of a body as the point of origin (I assume that the axis of rotation is orthogonal to that point, right?), but should I guess this body is connected to the axis of rotation or not?
However, in the case of a torque due to gravity, how should I imagine point O? Because in the end the axis of rotation passes through the point O and belongs to the body, right?

Comment: For me it is not clear what you ask. when you talk about "the torque due to gravity ". Is this on a pendulum or of what experiment do you think? Maybe you can add a drawing of the situation you think of?